# python return functions issue

Tags: python, recursion

Currently, I created a unique subid(a string) for every patient, and I created a function that checks the subid from the new patient that I'm currently adding and see either the subid is duplicated or not.

```
id = uuid.uuid4()

def checkValidsubId(subid: str) -> str: # subid should be unique value
    Allsubid = list(db.session.query(Patient.subid))
    for i in Allsubid:
        if subid in i:
            subid = id.hex # hex id
            return checkValidsubId(subid) 
        else:
            return subid
```

However, the problem is that im still getting errors for new subid that is not unique. So did I do somewhere wrong and how can I change it?

Comment: It *isn't* unique, you are re-using the same uuid you create outside the function.

Comment: so, this is recursive, perhaps infinitely so, and you only ever check the first id in `Allsubid`. You need to define what you are actually trying to do better.

Comment: if you just create a new `uuid4` you don't need to worry whether it is unique. It is. The sun will go supernova before you get a duplicate

Comment: Please note that `id` is a Python builtin function. Choose a different name for your variable

Comment: @Garr Godfrey thanks for noticing me, I almost forgot how many combination hex id can have

Comment: @Garr Godfrey, I somehow got the error: sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError, with a description of "UNIQUE constraint failed", so is there a reason that causes this to happen?

Comment: @EricssonCui *I already explained to you*, you are **re-using the exact same uuid, the one you defined outside the function**

Comment: how is subid generated before you make the call? Your function doesn't work. My point is you don't need it if you just call `uuid.uuid4()` every time you create a new subid

Comment: so, you'd have to show where you call this method. If `Allsubid` is a list of ids, your test `subid in i` is doing a substring search on the first id only, so it most cases it will just fall to the `else` and return the subid you passed in, even if it is in `Allsubid` list

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i don't know what exactly you are trying to do, but it looks like you might be trying to create a new uuid if the one given is already exists in your list. But, that's not what your code does. It never creates a new uuid4 and it only checks the first item in the list.

But, since it appears fine if you create a new uuid4, that's all you need. It won't be a duplicate:

```
def checkValidsubId(subid: str) -> str: # subid should be unique value
    return uuid.uuid4()
```

Of course, you notice this isn't using the `subid` you passed in. You didn't share the code that makes the call, but if you are getting duplicates it must be whatever you are passing is not a new uuid4(), because that's just not realistically possible.  Since you aren't encountering an infinite loop, I assume it isn't falling into the recursive condition.

BUT WHY WON'T IT BE A DUPLICATE?
For one, because it is long. But, a good UUID generator isn't random. A safe UUID will contain a unique ID from your computer, an unique ID from your running thread, a timestamp and an incremented value.  No two computers should generate the same UUID. The same computer can't do it on different threads, the same thread cannot do it at different times, and even if you called it twice in the time interval of a nanosecond, the incrementer will make it unique. Sadly, I don't think `uuid4()` is particularly safe, so if you really want a unique id:

```
def checkValidsubId(subid: str) -> str: # subid should be unique value
    Allsubid = list(db.session.query(Patient.subid))
    while subid in Allsubid:
        subid = uuid.uuid4()
    return subid;
```